# Questions on Windows performance against Linux

Tags: windows, linux

Many people claim that Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) has a lower memory footprint than Windows. Is this really true? E.g. between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Furthermore, why does Windows take considerably longer to boot up than Linux?

In both cases, the OS's are fresh - nothing installed on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Many people claim that Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) has a lower memory footprint than Windows. Is this really true? E.g. between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

As of now, yes, that is true. Windows (at least Vista and 7) tends to use a lot more memory because of a technology called SuperFetch which preloads the RAM with programs that you use frequently or recently. However, this makes programs a lot faster to launch. But on the other hand, Windows has a heck of a lot of graphics (and hence, memory) intensive effects. These effects are all-or-nothing. In Ubuntu, the effects are much more configurable, and are set to "Light" by default.

I'm sure some Free Software purists would argue that the code is a lot lighter because there are so many people looking at it, constantly tweaking it. This point isn't all too valid because a lot of open source projects are bloated too (see: OpenOffice.org, the original Mozilla suite, KDE 4.0).

> Furthermore, why does Windows take
>   considerably longer to boot up than
>   Linux?

Canonical works their butt off optimizing boot times. With the upcoming ChromeOS and Ubuntu Light and all that jazz, they need to use boot time as a market point.

In addition, Ubuntu and Linux in general doesn't have a registry, which is the bane of Windows users. The registry is so easily corrupted that you can't go 10 pages on the Internet without seeing a "Registry Fixing Program". Linux programs save their configurations in . in the user profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu 10.4 and Windows 7 dual boot system runs about the same memory footprint.  With only firefox running I see about 1 GB out of 8 GB available.  Ubuntu takes about 35 seconds from OFF to running, Windows 7 about 45 seconds, but I refuse to worry about 10 seconds difference for something that happens once a day.  Maybe your system is different.

If we're going to argue if Windows is better than Linux let's find something more important than this.